# mongodb fetch hundreds of data out of millions of data

Tags: mongodb

In my database, I have millions of documents. Each of them has a time stamp. Some have the same time stamp. I want to get some points (a few hundreds or potentially more like thousands) to draw a graph. I don't want all the points. I want every n points I pick 1 point. I know there's aggregation framework and I tried that. The problem with that is since my data is huge. When I do aggregation work, The result exceeds document maximum size, 16MB, easily. There's also a function called skip in mongodb but it only skips first n documents. Are there good ways to achieve what I want? Or is there way to make aggregation result bigger? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't used mongo in a long time, but couldn't you run a map reduce and funnel the output to one or more temporary collections?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think mapreduce will be too slow though it has the same effects as aggregation group.

Comment: To overcome 16MB limitation, M/R is a way to go. If it will be too slow or not, the only way to check is to measure it. If your collection will become really big, then consider `sharding`. In this case M/R job will be automatically dispatched to each shard in parallel.

Comment: No, you can't make the aggregation resulting document larger in the current version of MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can do this with either A/F or M/R - just skipping so that you have (f.e.) each 10th point is not something M/R allows you to do—unless you select each point based on a random value with a 10% change... which is probably not what you want. But that does work:

```
db.so.output.drop();
db.so.find().count();

map = function() {
   // rand does 0-1, so < 0.1 means 10%
   if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
       emit(this._id, this);
   }
}

reduce = function(key, values) { 
    return values;
}

db.so.mapReduce( map, reduce, { out: 'output' } );
db.output.find();
```

Which outputs something line:

```
{
    "result" : "output",
    "timeMillis" : 4,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 23,
        "emit" : 3,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 3
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
> db.output.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc4bc16473d7b84172d85"), "value" : { "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc4bc16473d7b84172d85"), "date" : ISODate("2013-08-05T15:24:45Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc75316473d7b84172d8e"), "value" : { "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc75316473d7b84172d8e") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc75316473d7b84172d8f"), "value" : { "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc75316473d7b84172d8f") } }
```

or:

```
> db.so.mapReduce( map, reduce, { out: 'output' } );
{
    "result" : "output",
    "timeMillis" : 19,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 23,
        "emit" : 2,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 2
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
> db.output.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc4bc16473d7b84172d83"), "value" : { "_id" :     ObjectId("51ffc4bc16473d7b84172d83"), "date" : ISODate("2013-08-05T15:24:25Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc4bc16473d7b84172d86"), "value" : { "_id" : ObjectId("51ffc4bc16473d7b84172d86"), "date" : ISODate("2013-08-05T15:25:15Z") } }
```

Depending on a random factor.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a good solution for picking "n" points (as it's literally random results).

Comment: But it was an interesting thought. Thanks!